# Please allow exiting the inline tag editor by pressing escape

Tags: feature-request, keyboard-shortcuts, inline-tag-editor

The inline editor can be closed by hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> - it is quite useful. Please allow it for the inline tag editor.

Comment: Close without committing any changes?

Comment: @hard: yep, thats what I mean.

Comment: We're six years later and this is still not implemented. The funny thing is that you could use the `Esc` key to exit the _**full**_ editor!

Answer (score 3):

So, that's quite annoying. Especially because I've hit 10k on MSE and now legally use the inline tag editor there.

[There's a simple user script I made for this purposes](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/10785-cancel-inline-tag-editor-with-esc), it essentially clicks the cancel button if the tag editor is focused.

Now you can "close the editor without committing any changes" ([the wording](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244803/please-allow-exiting-the-inline-tag-editor-by-pressing-escape/260028#comment800272_244803) by [hardmath](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155839/hardmath)).

Comment: Upvoted, also because you now *legally* use features...